# SharePoint 2010 - Organization Browser looses it self in hierarchy

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010

I have a problem with the Silverlight Organization Browser on MySite.

There seems to be some issue with getting the right data. In some cases, with no apparent pattern, the app wont show all the hierarchy. I can se my self, and my manager, and my manager's manager, but not the manager in the absolute top of the hierarchy. Sometimes i can, and sometimes i can't. To make it even more strange: at some times i see the top level manager, but depending on what user i click on, the top level boss may dissappear. I then have to reload the page to get him/her back, but the problem repeats it self as i click on certain people again.

I cant really get to the bottom of this... has anyone ever had these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the error was in the User Profile. The manager in the top had him self as manager. This probably created some weird circular reference that the Org. Browser could not handle.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem but the solution was slightly different.

One of the people in the management chain had a user that wasn't in the User Profile service used by My Sites as their manager so he and everyone below him in the hierachy had no upward management chain.

Setting the persons manager to a user that is included in the Profile Service got that peron and all subordinates' organisation tab display to show the management chain.

This post gave me a hint of where to look - thank you